# Input for Azure pipeline varaibles in release via UI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I can see that we can create variables in a group and add it to the pipeline and whose values can be given in the console if we select Powershell or cmd as task so when they create a release it waits for the user to enter that values in the console of Powershell or cmd

so is there **any way we can provide a simple WEB UI with options like checkbox or text boxes so that the user enters values required for variables in it and click on submit button**
then release will take this as input values of variables and proceed further with running task in releases

please suggest or help me with any article which helps me with example if you have any

Answer (score 0):

Your question refers to `parameters`. Using those you can have input from the user and use them later in your pipeline.For example using the below code you can choose from three options provided as a checkbox.

> Keep in mind that parameters are pre compiled in azure devops as a
> result their value is populated before the execution of the pipeline.

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - ubuntu-latest
  - macOS-latest

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.image }}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script

Using the input you got from parameters on the build pipeline you will need to pass them in the release pipeline. You can do that by using the below documented article.

https://blog.geralexgr.com/azure/pass-parameters-from-build-to-release-pipelines-on-azure-devops